# Do think we should be doing more to encourage the voting of questions?

Tags: discussion, voting

I have noticed, when compared to other stack sites, this site's users seem to refrain from rewarding a good question. This might be quite subjective, but I do thing as part of a successful Q and A site is the quality and usefulness to future users of the questions, we could maybe do a little more to encourage the practice?

Comment: *@Mild Fuzz* - I think it is just the nature of the 90-9-1 rule: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/participation_inequality.html

Answer (score 1):

Why bother?

A lot of questions are "why *this* doesn't work under circumstances *that*". It is useful (and sometimes even interesting), but not remotely general-purpose question that should gather ton of votes.

I think as volume of users and question grows there will be naturally more votes going around.

Comment: I see a lot of users don't select winners, so they are not participating in the community as we would like. I am interested to see whether there is a general awareness of that is how it works, or if people are generally just lazy/rude.

Comment: It's not really _winners_, answers are not competition. That is why unanswered question exclude those that have no accepted answers but have upvoted answers (and in that way accepted by community if not author of original question). I also had some answers sit for many days before getting accepted, some people just need time to figure everything out (especially without prior knowledge of stackexchange mechanics things can be confusing).

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - I'm with @Rarst on this one. I think we just need to be patient and let the community grow over time. I like how little drama we have on this site compared to StackOverflow. I think if the site grows slowly we might be able to create and maintain a really positive culture here. If we have lots of influx very quickly it could get juvenile and no fun to be here. Don't want that!